# What is the best way to make this drawing, animated way, in latex?

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, pgfmath, animations, animate

I would like to do this drawing in a beamer, for math classes, preferably in an animated way. I already tried to use the tables feature, but it was so so and without animated.

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\beamerdefaultoverlayspecification{<+->} %stepwise uncovering
\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage{tikz}

\newcounter{posx}
\newcounter{posy}

\newcommand{\ele}[1]{\draw [line width=1pt] (\theposx,\theposy) -- ++(1,0) -- ++(0,-1);
    \node [below] at (\theposx+.5,\theposy-.25) {#1};
    \addtocounter{posx}{1}
    \addtocounter{posy}{-1}
}

\newcommand{\sobe}{\fill [red] (\theposx+.5,\theposy+.2) circle (2pt);
    \fill [red] (\theposx-.5,\theposy+1.2) circle (2pt);
    \draw [blue, dashed, line width=1pt] (\theposx+.5,\theposy+.2) to [out=90, in=45] (\theposx-.5,\theposy+1.2);}

\begin{document}

    \begin{frame}

            \begin{tikzpicture}
            \ele{km$^2$}
            \ele{hm$^2$}
            \ele{dam$^2$}\sobe
            \ele{m$^2$}\sobe
            \ele{dm$^2$}\sobe
            \ele{cm$^2$}
            \ele{mm$^2$}

            \end{tikzpicture}

    \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: See  ` tikz` package. many examples are on   http://www.texample.net/ andhere on site (tag tikz-pgf).

Comment: @Zarko I tried, but I couldn't animate the red ball and the blue line.

Comment: Please show, what you try so far.

Comment: @Zarko See that... I edited the question and put the compilation result, now.

Comment: meanwhile you got answer which solve your problem :-) (without seeing what you try so far) :-)

Comment: @Zarko yes, I got the answer. Great. Tks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd just use loops and the `overlay-beamer-styles` library to get

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\beamerdefaultoverlayspecification{<+->} %stepwise uncovering
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{overlay-beamer-styles}
\begin{document}


\begin{frame}
\frametitle{An animation}
\begin{tikzpicture}[rdot/.style={circle,inner sep=0pt,minimum size=4pt,fill=red}]
 \draw[line width=1pt] (0,0) foreach \X [count=\Y] in {km,hm,dam,m,dm,cm,mm}
  { node[xshift=5mm,yshift=-5mm] {\X\textsuperscript{2}} -|++ (1,-1) };
 \path  (3-.5,-3+1.2)node[rdot](c3){} 
 foreach \X [count=\Y from 2] in {4,5,6} 
 { (\X-.5,-\X+1.2)node[rdot,visible on=<\Y->](c\X){}
 (c\the\numexpr\X-1) 
 edge[blue, dashed, line width=1pt,out=45,in=90,visible on=<\Y->] (c\X)
     };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @schrödingers-cat It was incredible, very good! Thank you